# AVLTree - Why is my search interface not working?

Tags: java, avl-tree

I have to implement an AVL Tree with some given interface functions. So far, everything seems to be fine, except when I call inside the main function "tree.search(3)" for example, it simply doesn't work and just returns one value or null. Does anyone have an idea why that is so?

AVLTree:

```
public class AVLTree implements SearchTree{

    public class Node {
        int key;
        int height;
        Node left;
        Node right;
        String string;

        Node(int key, String _string) {
            this.key = key;
            this.string = _string;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        AVLTree tree = new AVLTree();

        tree.insert(5, "gambo");
        tree.insert(9, "3");
        tree.insert(3, "3");

        System.out.println(tree.search(9));

        
    }
    private Node root;

    public Node find(int key) {
        Node current = root;
        
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.key == key) {
                break;
            }
            current = current.key < key ? current.right : current.left;
        }
        return current;
    }

    // public void insert(int key) {
    //     root = insert(root, key);
    // }

    public void delete(int key) {
        root = delete(root, key);
    }

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public int height() {
        return root == null ? -1 : root.height;
    }

    private Node insert(Node node, int key, String string) {
        if (node == null) {
            System.out.println("yep new node");
            return new Node(key, string);
        } else if (node.key > key) {
            node.left = insert(node.left, key, node.string);
        } else if (node.key < key) {
            node.right = insert(node.right, key, node.string);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("duplicate Key!");
        }
        return rebalance(node);
    }

    private Node delete(Node node, int key) {
        if (node == null) {
            return node;
        } else if (node.key > key) {
            node.left = delete(node.left, key);
        } else if (node.key < key) {
            node.right = delete(node.right, key);
        } else {
            if (node.left == null || node.right == null) {
                node = (node.left == null) ? node.right : node.left;
            } else {
                Node mostLeftChild = mostLeftChild(node.right);
                node.key = mostLeftChild.key;
                node.right = delete(node.right, node.key);
            }
        }
        if (node != null) {
            node = rebalance(node);
        }
        return node;
    }

    private Node mostLeftChild(Node node) {
        Node current = node;
        while (current.left != null) {
            current = current.left;
        }
        return current;
    }

    private Node rebalance(Node z) {
        updateHeight(z);
        int balance = getBalance(z);
        if (balance > 1) {
            if (height(z.right.right) > height(z.right.left)) {
                z = rotateLeft(z);
            } else {
                z.right = rotateRight(z.right);
                z = rotateLeft(z);
            }
        } else if (balance < -1) {
            if (height(z.left.left) > height(z.left.right)) {
                z = rotateRight(z);
            } else {
                z.left = rotateLeft(z.left);
                z = rotateRight(z);
            }
        }
        return z;
    }

    private Node rotateRight(Node y) {
        Node x = y.left;
        Node z = x.right;
        x.right = y;
        y.left = z;
        updateHeight(y);
        updateHeight(x);
        return x;
    }

    private Node rotateLeft(Node y) {
        Node x = y.right;
        Node z = x.left;
        x.left = y;
        y.right = z;
        updateHeight(y);
        updateHeight(x);
        return x;
    }

    private void updateHeight(Node n) {
        n.height = 1 + Math.max(height(n.left), height(n.right));
    }

    private int height(Node n) {
        return n == null ? -1 : n.height;
    }

    public int getBalance(Node n) {
        return (n == null) ? 0 : height(n.right) - height(n.left);
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(int key, String string) {
            root = insert(root, key, string);
    }

    @Override
    public String search(int key) {
        Node p = find(key);
        return p.string.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public long getCumulativeLengthOfSearchPaths() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
/**
 * Organizes strings with keys in a search tree and collects some statistics
 */
public interface SearchTree {
    /**
     * Inserts a string with a given key into the tree. The position in the tree
     * depends on the rank of the key with respect to all existing keys in the tree.
     * Each key is to appear in the tree at most once. Hence, this method will not
     * alter the tree if the key already exists in the tree.
     * 
     * @param key    the key of the string to be inserted
     * @param string the string to be inserted
     */
    public void insert(int key, String string);

    /**
     * Deletes a string with a given key from the tree.
     * 
     * @param key the key of the string to be deleted
     */
    public void delete(int key);

    /**
     * Searches for a string with a given key in the tree and returns the string if
     * it exists.
     * 
     * @param key the key of the string to be searched for
     * @return the string to be searched for, null if the key does not exist in the
     *         tree
     */
    public String search(int key);

   
    public long getCumulativeLengthOfSearchPaths();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue. In case someone runs into the same problem:

I added node.string as the string value, but it needs to parameter as the argument:

```
 node.left = insert(node.left, key, string);
```